# Why I can't move an image by JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have tryed to move an image whi with JQuery, when I press a key on keyboard, but it doesn't work. Could anyone what is the problem?

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).keydown(function(){
            $(document).find("img").animate({
                top:"+=100px",
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="player.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try adding 'position:relative;' to the image's CSS.

Comment: not relative, position must be absolute

Comment: @luizcarlosfx position must not be static, but can be relative

Comment: Your ready handler is useless here, your code should be: `$(document).keydown(function () {
    $("img").animate({
        top: "+=100px",
    });
});` http://jsfiddle.net/EfRp4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only thing you should change:

```
<img style="position: relative" src="player.jpg">
```

Comment: position relative looks more relevant, staying in page flow

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(){
        $('img').css('margin-top', '+=100px');
    });
});
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

you may have to change css

```
<style>
img {
  width:20%;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
</style>
```